# Setting up a Apache listening to the Amazon EC2 private DNS

Tags: apache, dns, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I've created a Apache virtual host for a Amazone EC2 private DNS. Just the way I did it with other hosts, too. But for some reasons, there is always a 403 (forbidden) when requesting it. To make it bulletproof I've copied the virtual host file from a working host, double checked all paths and hosts. It's enabled and Apache configuration files are reloaded. The way it works with any other host. But there is still that 403 requesting it from the same or another EC2 instance.

```
# host: ip-xyz.eu-west-1.compute.internal
# directory: /var/www/xyz
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName ip-xyz.eu-west-1.compute.internal
 DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz
 <Directory /var/www/xyz>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Jimbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the error log (for, well, errors), and the access log to verify you actually accessed the right machine.

**Edit**: If there is another wildcard VirtualHost declaration, delete it from the configuration.

Comment: The access log says the request is on the right machine, but the error log says there is something going wrong with the configuration: `client denied by server configuration: /var/www/`

Comment: I see. Somehow, access is attempted to /var/www (not /var/www/xyz); that access is denied. Check whether the web server can actually access /var/www. If yes, grep your config for other traces to `var/www`.

Comment: Access to /var/www (default host) is denied. Access is only allowed per host to sub directories like /var/www/xyz. Other hosts to e.g. /var/www/abc work. There is basically no difference to other hosts except host and path. That's why I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Looks like the vhost simply does not work for any reason. All request are handled by the default vhost. Therefore that 403.

Comment: I just played a little bit. Looks like the EC2 private DNS just does not work. It is always treated with the default settings not it's own vhost settings. Even adding it as a ServerAlias to another host does not work. Strange ...

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you meant with "wildcard VirtualHost declaration". All virtual hosts are defined by `<VirtualHost *:80>` because the IP changes. But disabling the default host works out. Directories are are still protected on access by not defined IPs/hosts. Thanks you. I thought disabling the default host might be a security risk or lead to unexpected errors, but access can be forbidden by a simple `<Directory>` in the configuration file, too. Hope that's correct. Thanks.

Comment: It turned out that a missing ServerName in the default host caused the problems. So I just defined `ServerName default` in the (first) default host and forbid all access. But I have still no idea why the problem was only related to the EC2 private DNS and not to other hosts. I hope this might also help some else. Thank you Martin for getting on the right way.